# Pass class variable to jquery function

Tags: jquery, variables, scope

I am having below tag with class attribute:

```
<tbody class="tbody_rowContent<%=tableCounter.intValue()+1%><%=count.intValue()+1%><bean:write name='BrandLevelSeasonilationVO' property='strProjectID'/>" style="none">
```

When I click on one button, I want this tbody tag contect to hide.So I wrote below function :

```
function call(tableCount,strProjectName,count){

var id="tbody_rowContent"+tableCount+count+strProjectName;;
alert(id);
$(document).ready(function(){
        $().hide();
    });


}
```

But I am not sure how to use id variable as a class name inside document.reeady function. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `ID` but `class`. The jQuery selectors are the same as in CSS, use dot (`.`) before the classname.

```
function call(tableCount,strProjectName,count){
    var class = "tbody_rowContent"+tableCount+count+strProjectName;
    alert(class);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.' + class).hide();
    });
}
```

Shorter version is

```
function call(tableCount,strProjectName,count){
    $('.tbody_rowContent' + tableCount + count + strProjectName).hide();
}
```

`Document ready` inside a function isn't necessary, you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `class` selector you must use dot anotation, not `#`

Maybe you don't need to use the document ready because the `HTML` will be rended when you click the button.

Try with this:

```
function call(tableCount,strProjectName,count){
    $(".tbody_rowContent"+tableCount+count+strProjectName).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var id="tbody_rowContent"+tableCount+count+strProjectName;;
alert(id);
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("."+id).hide();
    });
}
```